# (Rails, ActiveRecord) How do I use ActiveRecord calculations while still retrieving field names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any way to use ActiveRecord calculations while also acquiring relevant field names? For example, I'd like to find the average age of all people with the various last names. Basically I'd like to use:

```
   Person.average(:age, :group_by => "last_name")
```

... as a substitute for

```
   "Select last_name, AVG(age) FROM People GROUP BY last_name"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "acquiring relevant field names"?

Comment: Arbitrary fields of my choosing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works pretty much exactly as you have described (though I think you'd use :group instead of :group_by) for single fields.  The return is an OrderedHash, so the keys will be the last names and the values will be the average age for that last name.

Since any field that you return has to be included in the group, if you want to add additional fields, you can try doing something a little hackish.  In Postgres, for example, you can concatenate the additional fields like so:

```
Person.average(:age, :group => "first_name || ',' || last_name")
```

The keys in the return would be the comma separated first and last names.  If you're wanting ActiveRecord::Base objects returned, you have to resort to `"SELECT ..."` style queries.

Answer (score 1):

To return any attribute on the class you're averaging against you're probably better off using the standard `find(:all, ...)` method with a custom `:select` option.

So your example would be:

```
groups_of_people = Person.find(:all, 
  :select => 'avg(age) as avg_age, last_name', 
  :group => 'last_name')
```

They aren't really Person instances then (although they will be return as such) but you can do:

```
groups_of_people.each do |g|
  g.last_name
  g.avg_age
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Person.average(:age, :select => "last_name", :group => "last_name")
```

It returns an hash where the key is the value for_last name, the value is the result of the average calculation.

Comment: If you specify a :select value in the options then it uses that instead of the column for the group so you end up with a query like : SELECT avg(last_name) FROM people GROUP BY last_name

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it and it run the following query "SELECT AVG(last_name) as avg_last_name, last_name as last_name ..."

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I got. The requirement is that the averaged column is age not last_name. It is slightly odd - there's a line of code that just uses the value of the :select option instead of the column_name parameter if :select is present.